# Extract full sentence with list of words

Tags: python, regex

I hope to extract the full sentence, if containing certain key words (`like` or `love`).

```
text = 'I like blueberry icecream. He has a green car. She has blue car.'
pattern = '[^.]* like|love [^.]*\.'
re.findall(pattern,text)
```

Using `|` for the divider , I was expected `['I like blueberry icecream.']`

But only got   `['I like']`

I also tried `pattern = '[^.]*(like|love)[^.]*\.'` but got only `['like']`

What did I do wrong as I know single word works with following RegEx - `'[^.]* like [^.]*\.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think it would be easier to do this without regex. Just my two cents.

```
text = 'I like blueberry icecream. He has a green car. She has blue car. I love dogs.'
print([x for x in text.split('.') if any(y in x for y in ['like', 'love'])])
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put a group around `like|love`. Otherwise the `|` applies to the entire patterns on either side of it. So it's matching either a string ending with `like` or a string beginning with `love`.

```
pattern = '[^.]* (?:like|love) [^.]*\.'
```

Answer (score 2):

Research more and found out I was missing `?:`

```
text = 'I like blueberry icecream. He has a green car. She has blue car.'
pattern = '[^.]*(?:like|love)[^.]*\.'
```

Output

```
['I like blueberry icecream.']
```

Source: https://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/or-in-regex/

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex

```
regex = /[^.]* (?:like|love) [^.]*\./g
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/2SVWDc/1)